# How to tar all files and directories except one?

Tags: linux, shell-script, tar

I want to zip a directories and its files. For that I want to use `tar`. This directory contains a sub-directory called `ignore` which should not be included in the zipped file. How can I use `tar` to zip all of the files and directories in the main directory including hidden files (without `..` and `.`) except the `ignore` directory? The `tar` file should be in the main directory once created.

**EDIT**: I also tried:

```
tar --exclude mydir/ignore -zcvf mydir/mydir.tar.gz mydir/ --remove-files
```

But for some reason it fails with:

```
tar: mydir: Cannot rmdir: Directory not empty
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Why is that?

Comment: Hi abuka123, is this an assignment? Have you succeeded in doing something close to your goal? Please share it with us.

Comment: GNU tar has an --exclude-ignore=FILE (the man page entry is a little brief). You would need to echo mydir/ignore into the FILE first. Test it in case the man is misleading.

Comment: Is it your intention to archive the archive that you're creating, because that's what you're doing by creating the archive inside `mydir`.  Also, why are you surprised about the error message? The directory is _clearly_ not empty. You also mention `zip` a number of times, but this seems to be unrelated to what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda I want to archive the directory with it's content and place it into that directory (which should exist because `ignore` is still there). I could just use `mv` afterwards but isn't it possible to do with `tar`?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it had problems if you had a large number of files directly under the main directory. How many of those do you have? (You can check it with `ls main_directory`.) Also because your question changed.

Comment: @Quasímodo Sorry. it could be quite heavy as there is more then `>200` files/directory in the main directory.

Comment: No problem, I was just explaining myself ;) Now, why don't you simply remove `--remove-files` option and let the tar be in the parent directory? This would get rid of the errors and you would get your file. Explicitly, `tar --exclude mydir/ignore -zcvf mydir.tar.gz mydir/`